# Spring boot image display url

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hello i have images folder like this

[image]

What i want to do, is upload images to that folder and display them like this localhost:8080/image.jpg , so i can display it in frontend..
Nothing wrong is with upload, but i have no idea with displaying this images with api.

I already have tried

```
@Configuration
public class AdditionalResourceWebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("file:images/");
    }
}
```

But this is not working..

Comment: do you want to display these images in a browser by just hitting the url or you want to send this to frontend tech stack like javascript that will show the images

Comment: i want to send it to angular and display it there

Comment: Can you post the error that you got? Have you also looked at the argument that you gave the resource handler

Comment: i just get 403, and i also put this in  spring security configure    .antMatchers("/images**").permitAll()

Answer (score 1):

> What i want to do, is upload images to that folder and display them
> like this localhost:8080/image.jpg

URL should be `localhost:8080/images/image.jpg` as you are saving the images in `images` folder and mapping them as `/images` in `addResourceHandler` method

```
@Configuration
public class AdditionalResourceWebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**")
                  .addResourceLocations("file:images\\");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax of using `file:` is `file:///`. I would rather keep the static resources inside `resources/static` directory from where it should automatically be picked up by spring boot. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources) related to resource handling in spring